# QCoreApplication::postEvent priority has no effect

Tags: qt

I add 100+ events in events queue with *Qt::EventPriority::LowEventPriority*.

It takes 1-10 seconds to process each event.

I add one more event a bit later with priority set to *Qt::EventPriority::HighEventPriority*.

But, in my object's **customEvent** method I still receive those low priority events. The last high priority event is not coming, as if it was added with the same low priority as others.

Why?

Qt 5.7, Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, Windows 10.

Comment: Perhaps you add the high priority event after all the other events have been processed. Otherwise, please post a small self-contained test case that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What do you mean "processed"? My code did not processed them all, even half of them, at the time I added high priority event.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev, are you doing it for test purposes? Or you assume that in app the simultaneous posting of 100+ long processed events possible? Unfortunately for you it's how the event loop is designed - it takes all available posted events in a batch and locks until send them all. Then it repeats the batched send with new events in loop. So if you added a batch of 100+ events, they will be gathered to send in a batch, and that's why your HighPriority event doesn't work. If in real application this events are not batch-posted to loop, it would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design. The event loop is locked while it delivers the events. Any events you post to that event loop while it is locked will be appended after the current block of events has been delivered.